# SSHD taking random port

Tags: windows, openssh, sshd

I had configued `OpenSSH` in my windows server for port 22. But each time it is taking random port and as the random port is not active, the connection is getting closed.

```
sshd: PID 7148: Connection closed by <<ip_address>> port 60253
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: destination port is always 22, but origin port is random.

Comment: But I am getting this error `sshd: PID 7148: Connection closed by <<ip_address>> port 60253` in Event Viewer

Comment: That's the address and port your client `ssh` program (or similar like PuTTY) connected _from_, and as @Archemar said is random. `sshd` can handle connections from multiple clients, so each occurrence of this log message tells you which client connection is affected. The log message doesn't need to tell you which `sshd` port is affected because it's always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP communication is using two pairs of IP address and port. One of them is on the server and the other on the client side.

You server is correctly configured with some IP and port 22. Every new connection with every new client is using different port. This is the only way how to make it possible to connect from a single computer to multiple servers at the same time.

Comment: Correction: "... to connect to a single server to the same (22) port from many computers"